# Exposed my browser cookie of my request header

Tags: authentication, web-application, cookies

I exposed my browser cookie of my request header in a web forum.

After I realized what I have done - I logged out, cleared my browser and logged in again.

Am I safe now? Can someone still use that browser cookie to impersonate me?

Comment: Just simply use that cookie and see what will happen. You could for example use Cookie-Editor and add-on for Firefox or any other applicable for your browser.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Can someone still use that browser cookie to impersonate me?

As [@Hackndo](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/245064/250189) noted, this is totally **up to the web-developer**.

> am I safe now

Guessing, I would suggest you change your password, not just log out.

Here is a deterministic way to check:

- Now take your **cookie**, then log in (or change your password) and compare the 2 keys to see if they are the same.
- if they are not the same, make an **http request** with your old key, and see if it is valid. You say that it is **stored in cookies**, if so you can use [`curl`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15995919/how-to-use-curl-to-send-cookies) to send cookies. If the key is **stored in it's on header** (cookies are seperate), something like this

```
GET / HTTP1.1
Authentication-Key: "some_key"
Cookies: cookie1=something;cookie2=comething;
```

you can still use `curl` to [define custom headers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/356705/how-to-send-a-header-using-a-http-request-through-a-curl-call).

If the Authenticaiton Key is not send with either of these formats, you'll have to replicate your browser's behavior by looking in the network tab.

Answer (score 1):

This depends on the different websites on which these cookies were valid. Normally, if you have logged out, the cookies should no longer be valid, and you should be safe.

Sometimes websites do not invalidate cookies even after logging out, they simply delete them on the user side. In this case, it is still possible to re-authenticate by re-using the cookies. This behavior is a vulnerability and is **not normal**.

So for most websites, I think you should be safe, only I can't guarantee that this is the case for all websites for the reason above.